# How to add a log to the start and end of the Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

I need to perform some actions at the beginning and at the end.

expect: Print a start log, wait 3000ms, and then print 'hello world!' and 'end'.

```js
import { Observable, finalize, timer, map, } from 'rxjs'

const log = function <T>(o: Observable<T>): Observable<T> {
  // How to log at the beginning?

  // log at the end
  o = o.pipe(
    finalize(() => {
      console.log('end')
    })
  )

  return o
}

const o = timer(3000)
  .pipe(
    map(() => 'hello world!')
  )

log(o).subscribe((res) => {
  console.log(res)
})
```

Comment: what are "start" and "end"  in your understanding?

Comment: @Andrei I've updated the example to illustrate the beginning and end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understand is, you want to

1. log `'start'`
2. run `o` (whatever was passed to `log(o)`)
3. log `'end'`

I suggest the following, using `tap`, a higher order observable and `finalize` as you already did. The main trick here, is to start another pipe, that logs something *before* subscribing to `o`.

```
const log = <T>(o: Observable<T>): Observable<T> {
  of(o).pipe( // Creating a higher order observable here.
    tap(() => console.log('start')), // log start
    concatMap((o) => o), // run o
    finalize(() => console.log('end')) // log end,
  );
```

You don't need to use a higher order observable here, since `o` is available as function parameter.

```
const log = <T>(o: Observable<T>): Observable<T> {
  of(42).pipe( // Any value to start the pipe.
    tap(() => console.log('start')), // log start
    concatMap(() => o), // run o, from function parameter
    finalize(() => console.log('end')) // log end,
  );
```

No difference in function, just a matter of style, because I don't like passing useless values to `of()` just to start a pipe.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want the opposite of `finalize`, which doesn't exist, but we can make it!

```js
function initialize<T>(callback: () => void): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T> { // same typing as finalize operator
  return (source) => concat(
    EMPTY.pipe(
      finalize(callback)
    ),
    source
  );
}
```

So now you can do something like

```js
function logObservableStartAndEnd(o, msgStart, msgEnd) {
  return o.pipe(
    initialize(() => console.log(msgStart)),
    finalize(() => console.log(msgEnd))
  )
}
```

*(Caveat: None of the above has been debugged.)*

Answer (score 0):

If your `start` mean on subscribe, you can use [tap](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/tap), even observable is `EMPTY` also log `start`.

like this :

```
EMPTY.pipe(tap({
    subscribe: () => console.log('subscribe'),
    finalize: () => console.log('finalize'),
    // unsubscribe:() => console.log('unsubscribe'),
})).subscribe(console.log);
```

Answer (score -2):

I think you want to perform some action and then after sometime another action, so you can use

```
setTimeout(()=>{
    ......................
},1000)
```